# Request Entity Too Large error message in wcf

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Getting below error when sending Bytes with size 1-2MB.

The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Here is my code

Client side web.config:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRLSSplitterService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" >
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Here I have defined max range for buffer.
Please suggest if I am missing any thing to configure.

Comment: Please post your the entire system.serviceModel section of the **service's** config file - you received the error from the service; the client-side binding has nothing to do with this error.  Are you hosting the service in IIS?

Comment: tried this but no luck